# Custom recovery failing to flash on Nvidia Shield Tablet

Tags: rooting, clockworkmod-recovery

I am having problems rooting my Shield Tablet. It is the new B01 version with update 3.1, Android 5.1.1. I am trying to root using [this guide](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-root-nvidia-shield-tablet-android-5-0-lollipop-install-cwm-recovery-1481041), and I have successfully unlocked my bootloader, but flashing the custom recovery is where the problem lies.

I used fastboot flash recovery recovery.img, and it worked last time on Android 5.0.1, Shield update 2.2.2, but now after I flash it and go into recovery mode, it brings me to stock recovery.

I need to do this to root. Do you know how to fix my problem, or another rooting method that has been checked and works?

PS. I tried with TWRP, still no luck.

Comment: Did you try `fastboot boot recovery.img`?

Comment: No. What does that do, and how can it help?

Comment: I think I read something about a 'fine editor' in TWRP. What is this, what does it do, how does it work, and how can it help me?

Comment: Btw when I booted into recovery I saw an andrpod with a red triangle over it, but holding up and power brought me to stock recovery. Is this normal?